Why do my Windows filenames keep getting converted in FFMPEG?
I'm running a script that walks through a large library of .flac music, making a mirror library with the same structure but converted to .opus. I'm doing this on Windows 11, so I believe the source filenames are all in UTF-16. The script calls FFMPEG to do the converting.
For some reason, uncommon characters keep getting converted to different but similar characters when the script runs, for example:
06 xXXi_wud_nvrstøp_ÜXXx.flac

gets converted to:
06 xXXi_wud_nvrstøp_ÜXXx.opus

They look almost identical, but the Ü and I believe also the ø are technically slightly different characters before and after the conversion.
The function which calls FFMPEG for the conversion looks like this:
def convert_file(pool, top, file):
    fullPath = os.path.join(top, file)
    # Pass count=1 to str.replace() just in case .flac is in the song
    # title or something.
    newPath = fullPath.replace(src_dir, dest_dir, 1)
    newPath = newPath.replace(".flac", ".opus", 1)

    if os.path.isfile(newPath):
        return None
    else:
        print("{} does not exist".format(newPath))
   
        cvt = [
            "Ffmpeg", "-v", "debug", "-i", fullPath, "-c:a", "libopus", "-b:a", "96k", newPath]
        print(cvt)

        return (
            fullPath,
            pool.apply_async(subprocess.run, kwds={
                "args": cvt,
                "check": True,
                "stdin": subprocess.DEVNULL}))

The arguments are being supplied by os.walk with no special parameters.
Given that the script is comparing filenames to check if a conversion needs to happen, and the filenames keep getting changed, it keeps destroying and recreating the same files every time the script runs.
Why might this be happening?
edit: I have confirmed that if I manually execute the FFMPEG command in CMD, bypassing Python completely, it converts the original Unicode 0125 + 01410 to 0334 (U with umlaut), so this doesn't seem to be a Python problem.

It seems likely that the renaming is being done by ffmpeg.  Try running a command manually with a problem file name and see if the problem exists then.

How do you call Ffmpeg? Have you checked the contents of cvt immediately before the call? Instead of just print(...) you can use print(repr(...)) to show special characters as easily distinguishable escape codes.

@Mark I can confirm that the problem seems to persist if executing the commands manually by copy and pasting the original file name into notepad then copying from there to CMD. Python still detects the filenames as being different afterward.

@MichaelButscher there doesn't seem to be any special characters when using repr(), it just seems to be converting characters to similar characters.

I guess a simple solution would be to set the output filename for Ffmpeg to a temporary name with simple ASCII characters only, call Ffmpeg and rename the resulting file to its desired name. Alternatively you can try to apply a unicode normalization using unicodedata.normalize. This probably is done by Ffmpeg or Windows here.

@MichaelButscher I made a quick normalization script and it seems to have worked! No more of the same files showing up over and over again.
For some reason my script keeps detecting a few random file mismatches every time it runs, with no apparent pattern between them, but the big problem is dealt with. Thanks!
